# Reload avatar after upload w/o page refresh

Tags: javascript, avatar

I have an avatar upload which works fine, the problem is that when the upload has completed I want to update the avatar (if its in the top10) directly.
If the image is in the top10 it would have an id called 'chavatar'.

In a nutshell:
if there's an image with the id 'chavatar' on the page, reload that image's source.

How would I write that in javascript, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('chavatar').src = 'newimagepath.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

simply change the source of the image to the new one. this requires that your ajax upload function returns the url of the uploaded image. 
if you're using jQuery do something like this:

```
$('#chavatar').attr('src', 'new_image_path');
```

Comment: you mean: $("#chavatar") since there is no element <chavatar> :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery.   Something like:

```
$('#idofimgelem').html(<img src=urlofimg>)
```

Do this after the upload is done

Answer (score 0):

This informations can help you.

http://www.ultramegatech.com/2008/12/reloading-images-using-javascript/